# LaunchAgent ceased to work after upgrading to Big Sur (Error: Unable to access file on desktop)

Tags: permission, launchd

I had a home made LaunchAgent that worked fine in Catalina but after upgrading to Big Sur it refuses to launch. The agent is very simple, it just launches a java program (jar) I have on my desktop, ´/usr/bin/java /Users/x/Desktop/MyProgram.jar`.

The result is an error message:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile ~/Desktop/MyProgram.jar` and an `Error 1`.

(I am a little suprised that the error message specifically mentions `jarfile` - I interpret that as it is an error message from java rather than launchd)

Launching it manually from the terminal works fine.

I have a vague memory that I needed to grant permission to java and/or launchd to read access files on my desktop the first time I launched it when I created it. I have looked in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access/Files and Folders but couldn't see anything odd there. As a next step, I removed a couple of permissions that looked relevant from here thinking that it would trigger a new request for this specific permission, but it didn't.

E.g., I completely removed /usr/bin/java and Terminal.app, exiting the Terminal and opening it again - but I still can access files and folder with java/Terminal. Isn't that weird? Shouldn't that trigger a request from the system to give these programs permissions to access whatever?

**What do I need to do to make my Launch Agent work again?**

Comment: I thought ~ did not work in launchd so I am surprised that you say it used to work. I would replace ~ with what its actual value is. As java is reporting the error it is expecting a jarfile so puts that in the error to be more helpful

Comment: @mmmmmm That was just a shortcut I used to not spell out my username.

Comment: That rather wrecks the question as that is the big error I see and really stop reading as you have to correct that. I had even written out an answer then read again. Basically it is wasting reader time - put in a dummy user e.g. /Users/x or in your case /Users/d-b

Comment: IMO Placing _files_ that are used by **Launch Agents** on the **Desktop** is not a good practice, even if it works! Place the _files_ where having to grant access it not an issue, e.g. `/Users/Shared`. Another possibility is a user created _folder_ in the _root_ of your _home folder_ as it typically does not require additional permissions like the default _folders_ do.